# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'language' on class 'class java.lang.Class'

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

Im a getting the follwoing error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'language' on class 'class java.lang.Class'
```

Rest call used : /Test/rest/Languages/insertobj/Japanese/Swedish%206

I am using : org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;

I do had the specified property 'language' in my Languages class  so Im not sure why it is throwing the error. It works when I declare  its as such :

Languages lanobj = new Lanaguages();

//Languages class

```
public class Languages implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String language;
    private String displayName;

public Languages() {
        this.language = null;
        this.displayName = null;
    }


public Languages(String language, String displayName) {
    this.language = language;
    this.displayName = displayName;
}

public void setLanguageId(Long languageId) {
    this.languageId = languageId;
}

@Column(name = "language", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getLanguage() {
    return this.language;
}

public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language = language;
}

@Column(name = "displayName", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getDisplayName() {
    return this.displayName;
}

public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
}

}
```

///Resource manager code

```
@Path("{subResources}/insertobj/{language-id}/{displayname-id}")
//@POST 
@GET // Using get for the sake of making rest call with browser
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String getLanguageById(@PathParam("subResources") String id,
                            @PathParam("language-id") String language_id,
                            @PathParam("displayname-id") String displayname_id) 
{
    try{
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.test."+id);
        PropertyUtils.setProperty(c, "language",language_id);
        PropertyUtils.setProperty(c, "displayName",displayname_id);
        TransactionManager.createObject(c);     

    }catch (Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();      
    }

}
```

//TransactionManager snippet:

```
public static void createObject(Object entityObject) {
    Transaction tx = null;
    //SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().openSession();
    Session session =  SessionFactoryUtil.openSession();
    try {
      tx = session.beginTransaction();        
      session.save(entityObject);         
      tx.commit();
    } 
    catch (RuntimeException e)
    {
      if (tx != null && tx.isActive())
      {
        try 
        {
            // Second try catch as the rollback could fail as well
            tx.rollback();
        } 
        catch (HibernateException e1) {
            //logger.debug(“Error rolling back transaction”);
        }
        // throw again the first exception
        throw e;
      }
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setProperty` needs an instance whereas you are passing the class, see the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html)

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.test."+id);
Language language = (Language)c.newInstance();
PropertyUtils.setProperty(language , "language",language_id);
```

Either you specificially cast to `Language` or else you can just leave it as `Object`

```
Object object  = Class.forName("com.test."+id).newInstance();
PropertyUtils.setProperty(object, "language",language_id);
```

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but your original answer was three lines of code with no explanation. You have turned your text into an actual answer later. Some consider that bad style.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to set the property `language` on the Class object for `"com.test."+id`. You need to create an instance of this class to set the value on. Something like:

```
try{
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.test."+id);
    Object o = c.newInstance();
    PropertyUtils.setProperty(o, "language",language_id);
    PropertyUtils.setProperty(o, "displayName",displayname_id);
    TransactionManager.createObject(o);     

}catch (Exception exc){
    exc.printStackTrace();      
}
```

The class referenced by `c` must have a zero parameter constructor for this code to work.

Comment: this is unrelated to hibernate and rest btw.

Comment: Thank you it worked. Sorry I was unsure of what tag to use :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your class `Languages` is not having the default constructor defined the beanutils was not able to do a reflection.make sure you have the default constructor defined in your class.

Comment: I added a default constructor I am still getting the same error. Check the code edits above. Thanks